# Updating android version

Tags: updates, operating-system

I have Gigabyte GSmart Tuku T2 and it runs 4.0.4 version of android. I don't have update software option in my settings. Is there any way to update my android version to jelly bean?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option to look for updates (if the carrier has pushed any) is usually under "About phone".  I don't have that phone, but under "About phone" there should be a "System Updates" option.